# How to create guests VMs from different disk in ubuntu server

Tags: server, 20.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

this is my disk layout

```
loop2                       7:2    0  49.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18357
sda                         8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0 221.5G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
sdb                         8:16   0 223.6G  0 disk 
sdc                         8:32   0   5.5T  0 disk 
sdd                         8:48   0   5.5T  0 disk
```

I want to create guests VMs (KVM)  from sdc disk. How can I successfully implement?